# Meaning of "costs throughout to" in a court case?

Tags: canada, civil-law, british-columbia, language, legal-terms

A judge said, "I would therefore dismiss the appeal with costs throughout to the respondent."

Excuse my simple post here. I looked for an answer on google, but could not find any. I would like to confirm my assumption of the meaning being all costs to be covered by the respondent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The court is ordering the appellant to pay the respondent for any court costs it has paid.

The losing party in a lawsuit is frequently ordered to reimburse the prevailing party for whatever it costs it may have incurred. Those costs typically come in the form of fees for various actions taken by the clerk, from the filing of the complaint to sending subpoenas, to paying witnesses for their time.

"Costs throughout to Party X," or more frequently, "Costs to Party X" are common ways to note that the court is making that order.

Answer (score 0):

BDB484's answer is correct -- the only thing to add, because it is somewhat unclear based on the plain meaning of the word, is that "costs" in litigation **do not** include attorney's fees.

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our tour page.  You can see the link at the bottom of the page.